# Visual studio code overwrites freshly pulled files from GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a project with a partner. Lately, he started to raise the suspicion that some of his work gets overwritten by me. Today, after doing git pull, i realized he is probably right: one of the files he worked on appeared correctly in the beginning, but then, suddenly(and i have no idea why and how), that file "rolled back" to its state before his commit.

This is of course unacceptable. Problem is, that i really like this IDE. Is anybody here familiar with this issue, and knows how to deal with it?

Comment: Was your VS opened? Was it a source file or something like project? Was the file opened in VS? Did VS offer to reread the file? Do you see the changes forth and back in the git history?

Comment: Was your VS opened? Yes. Was it a source file or something like project? Was one of the many files in the project. Was the file opened in VS? You, mean, created there? Not sure.  Did VS offer to reread the file? No. Do you see the changes forth and back in the git history? I saw the "overwritten" changes, after i made a commit on my own. I didn't notice the file was overwritten, so i committed.

Comment: "You, mean, created there?" - no, I mean opened in the code editor. "Did VS offer to reread the file? No" - check [this setting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/09/14/detect-when-a-file-is-changed-outside-the-environment/); if it is set and you don't see the dialog this is strange. "Do you see the changes forth and back in the git history? I saw the "overwritten" changes, after i made a commit on my own" - but there is also the change forth, as you merged the other developer's change?

Comment: By "opened", do you mean appearing in one of those file tabs in the upper panel? Yes, it was :-) I like to keep those tabs, in order to navigate quickly between frequently worked-on files. Vs code didn't offer to reread. About that setting: I didn't manage to find it. Notice that i use Visual studio code- not Visual studio. I don't even have any "tools" menu. I didn't understand your last question :-)

Comment: "Notice that i use Visual studio code- not Visual studio". Ah, sorry. It's very different thing then. I'm afraid I don't know much about it.

Comment: I see...well thanx anyway :-)